# How to specify text-only subtitles in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to script some basic DVD-to-home media server processing. One of the things I'm trying to do, which seems like it should be pretty basic, is extract the text (srt) subtitles from the .mp4 file from the initial rip.

I can see the stream, and if I select the stream explicitly (by stream number), I can extract it. However, I want to script the ffmpeg command. If I try to just specify the subtitle stream with a -map option, it maps the first subtitle stream, which is often a bitmap stream instead of text stream.

So, after ripping some of my DVD's, I'd like to process everything in a batch script, something like:

```
for video in *.mp4; do
  ...
  (special code to get $subtitle filename with .srt instead of .mp4)
  ffmpeg -i "$video" -map 0:s "$subtitle"
  ...
done
```

I'd like the "-map" option to cause ffmpeg to select only text-based subtitles (like mov_text), and not, for example, dvd_subtitle, irrespective of which is first in the list of streams.

Does anybody know of a way to do this?